# Is texture name unique in OpenGL?

Tags: multithreading, opengl, textures

When I create a texture using `glGenTextures`, I get a texture name which is actually an integer such as 0,1,2,3...
What the texture name actually mean? Is this the unique index in GPU?
If I create a texture in different threads or processes, I may get the same name.
However I don't think same name means same texture in GPU.
So I guess the texture is just the local texture index in per thread. 
So it is impossible to share texture between thread right?

Comment: You've never gotten 0 back from a successful execution of `glGenTextures`. [0 doesn't represent a texture object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Object#Object_zero); it represents the absence of a bound texture (which has some very odd effects, as it acts like a number of texture objects, but forget I said anything about that). The point being, object 0 is not a normal object.

Answer (score 3):

Texture object names are numbers that represent a specific texture. If you generate a texture object name, the system guarantees that it will uniquely identify that specific texture within that [OpenGL context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context), until you delete the texture (and likely sometime thereafter).

And technically, it is unique with the set of contexts that share objects with the current OpenGL context.

But outside of the context sharing group, that texture name has no meaning. It means nothing to the GPU itself; it merely refers to a specific texture.